# mikrotik: ip forward between two local networks

Tags: mikrotik

I have two local networks and a public one connected to my Mikrotik via VLAN. I want the local networks to see each other without any nat. So I have the following config on my Mikrotik. But the local networks can't see each other.

```
/ip address
add address=192.168.1.1/24 interface=vlan1 network=192.168.1.0
add address=192.168.2.1/24 interface=vlan2 network=192.168.2.0
add address=172.16.16.1/24 interface=vlan3 network=172.16.16.0
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=forward
add action=accept chain=input
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=!192.168.2.0/24 src-address=192.168.1.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-address=!192.168.1.0/24 src-address=192.168.2.0/24
```

Comment: Are the provided rules the complete set of FW rules. Have you tried removing the masquerade rules completly just as a test?

Comment: Do the computers in the LAN networks have the Mikrotik as gateway ? Or do they have routes installed to the other LAN network via the Mikrotik?

Comment: @eKKiM Yes. It is all of them. I need masquerade rules for connecting local networks to public network.

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON Yes. All computers in LAN networks have the mikrotik as gateway.

Comment: Can the computers ping each other (disable temporarily firewall on the computers to be sure that ping is not blocked) ?  if not, what is the result of a "tracert -d"  ?

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON no they can't. Also tracert failed like this (ping from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.2.2):
 1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: Can computers on the same network ping each other, ie. 192.168.2.3 can ping 2.2 ?

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON , Yes, They can. even if I remove dst-address in masquerade rules, everythong works fine.